# Removing Alias in SSH

Tags: ssh

I am new to web hosting, and I am trying to set up Laravel on my web server. One of the instructions during the installation was to set up an alias for composer. I accidentally set the wrong alias, is there any way to change this?

This is the SSH command I used (in PuTTY)

```
echo 'alias composer="php -d extension=phar.so -d allow_url_fopen=On /home/testuser/composer.phar"' >> ~/.bashrc source ~/.bashrc
```

Now whenever I try to run composer using this -

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel testproject
```

I get this error -

```
Could not open input file: /home/testuser/composer.phar
```

How can I change the alias to "testinguser" ?

Comment: Delete that line from your `.bashrc`.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using PuTTY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to the machine, edit your `.bashrc`, and change `testuser` to `testinguser`.

Comment: I am accessing this via putty. How do I access .bashrc?

Comment: You login to the shell with putty, and run an editor like `vi` or `pico`.

Comment: Are those separate downloads? Just to confirm, I cannot edit/delete my .bashrc through PuTTY alone? (Meanwhile downloading Pico)

Comment: They aren't downloads, they're programs that should already be installed on the server. You use PuTTY to login to the server, and then run one of these programs to edit your file. I'm not going to try to give you a crash course in using Unix, Stack Overflow is for questions about computer programming.